# JSON parsing giving exception in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using following code for other JSON data its working but here it gives dictionary exception it has small amount of data.

This is data which i am parsing

```
   { "affectedDate": 1310515200000, 
   "category": "Sport", 
   "content": "Kl 2100 hver tredje lørdag i måneden arrangerer Harvey's en interaktiv  fotballquiz på våre 13 HD-skjermer. Nivået er høyt, men samtidig er det underholdning i form av videoproduksjoner og midt i blinken for enhver fotballinteressert kristiansander. Quizen er myntet på folk som har lyst å lære litt om fotball - og ikke bare de som vet hvor mange fly som gjennomsnittlig flyr over Goodison Park. Det er 1-4 personer pr lag og gratis påmelding i baren på Harvey's eller på tlf 380 72305. Umbro er hovedsponsor av Harvey's Saturday Night Football Quiz og stiller med flotte rundepremier! \n
```

\n
Vi har også en maratontabell bestående av alle resultatene fra 2011s runder, men hvor vi stryker hvert lag sine fire dårligste poengsummer foran finalen i desember. Laget som vinner sammenlagt sender vi til EM i Polen og Ukraina neste sommer!\n
\n
Utvalgte deler av tidligere quizer, soundtrack, maratontabell og annen informasjon finner du for øvrig på våre hjemmesider www.harveys.no\n
\n
Vi garanterer at dette er en månedlig fotballhappening å få med seg!", 
          "eventId": 15946, "image": "http://shelf-media.s3.amazonaws.com/39be3cbc5584eb0e9f61c9926a62d478_gmedium.jpg",

```
   "latitude": "58.1441382", 
  "longitude": "7.9933589", 
  "title": "HARVEY'S SATURDAY NIGHT FOOTBALL QUIZ" } 



SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=event&appid=620&eventid=15946&affecteddate=1310515200000"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
appDelegate.books1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
appDelegate.dates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.descriptionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", results);

for (int i=0; i<[results count]; i++) {
  Detail  *aBook = [[Detail alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:i]];      
  [appDelegate.descriptionArray addObject:aBook];
  [aBook release];  
}
```

Comment: When posting code or other "code like" text, highlight the code section and press the `{}` icon above the text edit window to format the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the actual web page the outermost structure is an "object" (dictionary).  But you parse the input string twice, once expecting a dictionary and the second time an array (it can't be both).  It's the array you're accessing when you get the error, I suspect.  (Can't tell for sure since you didn't provide any log or other error info.)

In general, you need to test (with `isKindOfClass`) the type returned from a JSON parser, to make sure it's the type you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Detail  *aBook = [[Detail alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
```

You are making an assumption that all the objects inside your `results` array are `NSDictionary` objects - JSON can contain *both* dictionaries and arrays, so this is far from guaranteed.

Comment: i dont have any array inside results i am showing you results NSlog

Comment: You haven't shown ANY results, error messages, etc.  No clue as to what your input data looks like.

Comment: i have show the json data which i am parsing posted in question now

Comment: You also haven't shown the exception you're actually getting. So we sort of have to guess. You should provide the actual exception being generated.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d15b30'

Comment: See my answer.  You're treating a dictionary as an array.

Comment: What he said. But also, don't assume anything about your input: your JSON may only have dictionaries now, but who knows what's in it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string contains a dictionary as its root object, not an array, so it is initialized as `NSDictionary` by the `objectWithString:` method. `NSDictionary` doesn't have an `objectAtIndex:` method which is why you see the exception when trying to call it.